# Spring Java Mongodb Aggregation check userId in array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a MongoDB database with users and questions.

My Question document:

```
{
"_id" : "b943d57a-f4c3-4394-86f7-dd1d1b5e2563",
"_class" : "org.company.app.model.Question",
"statement" : "First question for testing purposes",
"userMail" : "themail@mail.com",
"responses" : [ 
    {
        "responseId" : "6b60e900-0fec-47d2-8853-e1ea3508abe6",
        "responseType" : "TEXT",
        "mail" : "themail2@mail.com",
        "responseTime" : ISODate("2017-11-22T11:23:10.848Z"),
        "data" : "New Response 1",
        "likes" : [ 
            "themail3@mail.com", 
            "themail5@mail.com"
        ],
        "dislikes" : [],
        "state" : "PUBLISHED",
        "stateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-22T11:23:10.848Z")
    }
  ],
"categories" : [ 
    "Category1", 
    "Category2", 
    "Category3"
],
"creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-26T14:50:12.717Z"),
"lastUpdateTimestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-02T15:35:20.818Z"),
"deleted" : false,
"active" : true,
"state" : "PUBLISHED"
}
```

and the user document:

```
{
"_id" : "1f4b5091-c755-4083-880e-e1c4696f7236",
"_class" : "org.company.app.model.User",
"allowsComms" : true,
"registrationConfirmed" : false,
"placeOfWork" : "Urban records",
"name" : "John",
"surname" : "Doe",
"mail" : "themail3@mail.com",
"phone" : "[ \"1111111111\" , \"2222222222222\"]",
"birthDate" : ISODate("1971-12-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
"gender" : "MALE",
"nationality" : "US",
"language" : "en",
"socialNetworks" : {
    "INSTAGRAM" : "@instagram",
    "TWITTER" : "@twitter"
},
"specialty" : "alternative rock",
"subspecialty" : "sub_3",
"creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-31T10:13:12.131Z"),
"lastUpdateTimestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-13T10:23:37.637Z"),
"deleted" : false,
"active" : true,
"profileImage" : "image"
}
```

From that point, I'm creating a new aggregation to join both collections, get user information and count likes and dislikes instead of return all the user ids at that array.

```
public List<JoinedResponse> getResponses(String userId, String questionId, long itemsPerPage, long requestedPage) {

    Assert.hasLength(questionId, "questionId cannot be null or empty");


    MatchOperation questionIdMatch = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("_id").is(questionId));
    MatchOperation responsesStateMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("responses.state")
            .in(QuestionState.PUBLISHED.toString(), QuestionState.APPROVED.toString()));

    LookupOperation userInfoLookUpOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("User").localField("$responses.mail").foreignField("mail")
            .as("userInfo");


    ProjectionOperation fieldsProjectionOperation = Aggregation.project(Fields.from(
            Fields.field("responseId", "$responses.responseId"),
            Fields.field("responseType", "$responses.responseType"),
            Fields.field("mail", "$responses.mail"),
            Fields.field("responseTime", "$responses.responseTime"),
            Fields.field("data", "$responses.data"),
            Fields.field("state", "$responses.state"),
            Fields.field("userName", "$userInfo.name"), 
            Fields.field("userSurname", "$userInfo.surname"),
            Fields.field("profileImage", "$userInfo.profileImage")))
            .and("$responses.likes").size().as("likes")
            .and("$responses.dislikes").size().as("dislikes");


    // Creates the Aggregation: THE ORDER IS IMPORTANT!!!
    Aggregation ag = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            questionIdMatch, 
            Aggregation.unwind("responses"),
            responsesStateMatch,
            userInfoLookUpOperation, 
            Aggregation.unwind("userInfo"),
            fieldsProjectionOperation,
                Aggregation.project("responseId", "userName", "userSurname", "mail", "responseType", "responseTime",
                    "data", "likes", "dislikes", "profileImage", "state"/*, "isLiked"*/),
            Aggregation.skip((long) ((requestedPage - 1) * itemsPerPage)), 
            Aggregation.limit(itemsPerPage));

    logger.debug(ag.toString());
    AggregationResults< JoinedResponse > output = mongoTemplate.aggregate(ag, "Question",
            JoinedResponse);
```

Well, at this point, I need to know if the userId is in the liked or disliked list and I have spend a lot of hours investigating with no result. Of course, I would like to do it with aggregation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: liked list contains array of emails not user ids

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I want an object with the fields you can see enumerated plus one more indicating if the user mail is in the likes list.

Comment: @Veeram yes, the mail is the userId

Comment: You can use `isliked:{$in:["$mail","$responses.likes"]}`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, but where exactly must I put that line?